# Generalization of $\lambda$-directedness

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits

It is well known that objects in $\mathbb{Set}$ whose hom-functors preserve
$\lambda$-directed colimits,i.e. colimits whose schemes are $\lambda$-directed posets are those sets whose cardinality is $<\lambda$. My question is how
do look sets whose hom-functors preserve colimits whose schemes are **linearly ordered posets of length $\lambda$** ? I.e. especially not necessarily well-ordered posets.

Comment: What do you call length of a poset ?

Comment: @MaximeRamzi I say that the poset is linearly ordered. Hence it has a length (the cardinality of the underlying set). $\mathbb{Z}$ as a poset has length $\aleph_0$.

Comment: Your title says “generalization” but this is a special case of a $\lambda$-directed poset. In any case, such a set must again have cardinality less that $\lambda$, at least if $\lambda$ is a regular cardinal. This holds even for a set whose hom functor preserves colimits indexed by well ordered sets of lengths up to $\lambda$.